# Python:How do I reindex a grouped dataset with a custom order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the data grouped exactly how I want, however the months are out of order.

```
sign_off=df1.groupby(['Sign off','LOB']).sum()
print(sign_off)
```

results in

```
                          Test Cases
Sign off     LOB                    
April2019    Sales            135
April2020    Systems          36
             Others           49
August2019   Systems          13
             Sales            414
             DevOps           47
February2019 Systems          42
February2020 Systems          76
             Sales            151
January2019  ECS              251
             Systems          157
             Sales            116
July2019     Systems          45
             Sales            9
June2019     Systems          164
March2019    ECS              37
             Systems          181
March2020    Systems          13
May2019      Systems          7
May2020      Systems          249
             Others           60
November2019 Systems          49
October2019  Systems          479
             Sales            130
```

That's how I want it formatted, but months are in alphabetical order (I would like to keep them in this string format).  So now I need to reorder the Sign off months, and I have tried this:

```
order = ['January2019','February2019','March2019','April2019','May2019','June2019','July2019','August2019','October2019','November2019','February2020','March2020','April2020','May2020']
sign_off.reindex(order)
```

This results in the error: `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

I need it to reorder the dataset based on the month column.I'd like the months to be in the order I specified with the correct Line of Business and Test Cases associated to the month.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead, use `as_index=False` on your groupby to get the columns out of the index and then do the rest:

```
sign_off=df1.groupby(['Sign off','LOB'], as_index=False).sum()
df['Sign off'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sign off'], format='%B%Y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%m%Y')
df.sort_values(by=['Sign off'], inplace=True)
df['Sign off'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sign off']).dt.strftime('%B%Y')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Sign off      LOB  Test Cases
9   January2019      ECS       251.0
15    March2019      ECS        37.0
17    March2020  Systems        13.0
0     April2019    Sales       135.0
1     April2020  Systems        36.0
18      May2019  Systems         7.0
19      May2020  Systems       249.0
14     June2019  Systems       164.0
12     July2019  Systems        45.0
3    August2019  Systems        13.0
22  October2019  Systems       479.0
```